# Python CSV File writing contents to file

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write and append values to CSV file. Whenever I am executing the script Header values are printing multipletimes. When I open the excel sheet I see

[image]

Instead of

[image]

My code:

```
with open('names.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['Header1', 'Header2', 'Header3']
    writer= csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'Header1':'%s'%(a),'Header2':'%s'%(b),'Header3':'%s'% (c)})
```

Comment: What is the definition of `a`, `b` and `c`? Are you calling the same code multiple times? As you have the file opened for append, it might be the reason why the header is repeated.

Comment: @kristof    a,b,c are variables. Yes I am executing same code. I am trying to append only rows not headers. I don't know where things are going wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you're executing the same code multiple times, you'll end up with multiple calls to `writer.writeheader()`. This is the cause for the header being repeated in your resulting file.

Instead of calling the code multiple times (and opening the same file over and over, appending each time), you could pass the contents you want to write in an iterable (e.g. a `list` of `dict`s):

```
define write_to_file(rows):
    with open('names.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ['Header1', 'Header2', 'Header3']
        writer= csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()

        for row in rows:
            writer.writerow({'Header1': row['a'],
                             'Header2': row['b'],
                             'Header3': row['a']})
```

There's also no reason to use string formatting to define a `dict`.

Comment: I cannot pass variable a directly. Variables a,b,c are input parameters in script. Also I tried your solution but no luck

Comment: Without your code, there's little more I can suggest. You'll have to restructure your in some way though, to avoid writing the CSV header multiple times.

Comment: How should I define Rows in this scenerio?

Comment: `rows` is a `list` of `dict`s